# Netbeans macro, how do I jump to end of line?

Tags: netbeans, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm warming up to Netbeans (& IDEs) and I'm stumped on how to jump to the end of the line (without reaching for the end key).

say I type (assume cursor/caret is vertical bar):

```
  $myarray = ('0' => 'some string|')
```

is there a key combo or macro that will jump me to the end of the line?

I tried to set TAB to do this as a macro, but it doesn't work, I assumed TAB was special so I tried SHIFT+SPACE after that & still no luck, here is my macro:

name: cursor to eol
shortcut: Shift+SPACE
macro code: caret-end-line

I'm using:
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 (Build 201011082200)
Java: 1.7.0_01; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 21.1-b02
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to record a macro for that, this is what i did.

1- In Netbeans, click somewhere in the text editor.

2- Select Edit > Start Macro

3- Now whilst in the editor, press the ‘end’ key.

4- Select Edit > Stop Macro

5- Give your macro a name (eg. “End of Line”)

6- Click ‘Set Shortcut’

7- Press “ctrl” and any other character, example ( B ) and click OK

Now when you press ctrl + B your courser is in the End of the line...

Comment: Ya, I updated and all of a sudden it started working, so who knows? But you get the answer for trying!